# Find objects that match today's date in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a calendar object that lists a number of object events. Each event contains a start_date. So when I call

```
event.start_date it gives me "8/6/2017 3:00pm"
```

I want to be able to find all the events with today's date. I'm using Chronic. So

```
Chronic.parse('today') would give me "8/6/2017 00:00:00" or something like it
```

I'm not using Rails just Ruby. Thus, I don't have all the special methods that come with Rails to help me with this.

If I enter a specific date I could find the events with that specific date by using

```
event.start_date.starts_with?("8/6/2017")
```

but I haven't figured out how to do it with today's date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time = Chronic.parse('today')
target_date = Chronic.parse('8/6/2017').to_date
puts time.to_date == target_date
```

`Time` class (what Chronic returns) holds datetimes. `Date` only holds dates. If you convert `Time` to `Date`, you discard the time-of-day information, and then you can compare just the date itself.

Note that `Date.today` is the same thing as `Chronic.parse('today').to_date` (and same as `Time.now.to_date`). Also note that `Time` class doesn't have `#to_date` unless you `require 'time'`, but Chronic does it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is perfect. Didn't see the to_date method in the Class: Time Ruby docs.

Comment: Because it isn't there :) Read the "additional notes" [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-to_date).